# How to implement "debounce" with Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, debouncing

In our application we have a lot of AutoSave - meaning every change a user makes things are being automatically saved within 300 milliseconds.

Also we have a lot of extreme caching, because the application has a lot of peak loads.

Usually we use Azure ServiceBus to send messages to all instances to invalidate a certain "group" - meaning it will get a fresh copy from the database.

Invalidating cache and getting a fresh copy is a relative expensive operation, so we don't want to do this every 300ms.

There is no big need for emptying the cache instant, but it would be great if we can do this i.e. a minute after the last change.

So I'm looking for a debounce concept.

- Preferably on the Azure Service side so I don't have to think about it on the client side
- And to severely limit the amount of messages that are being sent to all instances.
- Preferably not with extra stuff that needs to be maintained - like an extra web app that does the debouncing logic

What is the best solution? Or do I need to write something myself?

[image]

Comment: You haven't mentioned whether you are using Topics or queues in ASB. For a single signal to be sent to multiple instances, I would think of using `signalR` group message as much simpler alternative.

Comment: I'm using Topics - my current architecture is in Azure ServiceBus so on short term preferably I'm not changing too much on that.